# Is there any way to clone sumoselect dropdown in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, sumoselect.js

I am using [jquery sumoselect](https://hemantnegi.github.io/jquery.sumoselect/) library for showing multiselect dropdown.
Now i want to clone this drop down on click of button.
Is there any way to achieve this?

```
$('#chtml').clone().attr('id', 'newid').appendTo('p');
```

I have tried above code where #chtml is the id of td in which my multiselect drop down present and i want to copy this into `<p></p>` tag.

Comment: Post a working code snippet demonstrating your problem.

Comment: You'll need to clone the `select` then instantiate the SumoSelect on it again

Comment: this worked in the console on the [demo page](http://hemantnegi.github.io/jquery.sumoselect/sumoselect_demo.html), as proof of concept.. `$('.testselect1').clone().appendTo(".highlight:eq(0)").SumoSelect();`

Comment: You have not chosen answers for any of your questions. Please hit the check mark next to the answer that solves your problem in all of your questions.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be 2 problems with your attempt..

1. The library creates `<p>` tags, so simply appending to `$("p")` is literally going to insert the select element into the existing `SumoSelect` instance.
2. The library hides the original `<select>` so you're appending an invisible select element anyway. Solve this by calling `SumoSelect()` on the clone.

PS. There's really no need to give it a new id, just remove the existing one.

```js
$("#chtml").SumoSelect();

$("#chtml").clone().removeAttr("id").appendTo("#cloneGoesHere").SumoSelect();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.sumoselect/3.0.2/jquery.sumoselect.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.sumoselect/3.0.2/sumoselect.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<select name="somename" id="chtml" tabindex="-1">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<p id=cloneGoesHere></p>
```